# Re-render text on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a React (Next.js) app that contains a counter regressive (10 seconds), I have this code:

```
let [time, setTime] = useState(10);
  setTime = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (time > 0) {
        console.log(time);
        time -= 1;
        setTime();
      }
      else {
        console.log("end");
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
  setTime();
```

Then:

```
return (
    <>
      <span>{time}</span>
    </>
)
```

Ok, that works fine on console, print 10, then 9, then 8, and so on until it reaches 0, but the tag `<span>` keep showing 10 (the initial value).

Thanks, and hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how you are using the state hook. You are modifying the `time` value, and you are mutating it inside the `setTimeout` closure. Please check out how state should be handled: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html.

```js
const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

// somewhere else
setTime(time => time - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use should use `setState` to update the `state`

Try this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    time: 10,
  };
  setTime = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.time > 0) {
        console.log(this.state.time);
        this.setState((prev) => ({ time: prev.time - 1 }));
        this.setTime();
      } else {
        console.log("end");
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <span>{this.state.time}</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.setTime}>Start counter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try usEffect hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
useful to handle side effects in your component

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTime((time) => time - 1);
    }, 1000);
  });

  return <span>{time}</span>;
}
```

SandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-swanson-heiec?file=/src/App.js